# Property of a property not being set?

Tags: objective-c

I have OJTest.h containing:

```
@property (nonatomic) int testVal;
```

In ViewController.h:

```
#import "OJTest.h"

@property (strong, nonatomic) OJTest *testObject;
```

In ViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.testObject.testVal = 100;
NSLog(@"%i", self.testObject.testVal);


}
```

Yet the console prints 0. What am I missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: Where do you create self.testObject?

Comment: It is declared in ViewController.h?

Comment: You need to alloc/init the object before you can use it.

Comment: ok, I'm with you now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `testObject` is not being created.
Try the following in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.testObject = [[OJTest alloc] init];
self.testObject.testVal = 100;
```